# Is there a way to pull price data in R using an equities ISIN or SEDOL using tq_get? (international equities in particular)

Tags: r, quantmod, stockquotes, tidyquant

I am attempting to pull price data for a bunch of international equities using `tq_get` in the `tidyquant` package but am having issues pulling the data based on the ticker, since the data I have only has ISIN and SEDOL as identification values. When I enter either into the search bar in yahoo finance, the correct equity shows up (and I assume that tq_get uses yahoo finance) but when I enter it in the code where the ticker would go I get an error message.

I have tried entering both the ISIN and SEDOL values into the code and each returns an error.

Alibaba (BABA) - listed in the US so that is not the issue...

SEDOL:

`test1 <- tq_get("BP41ZD1", get = "stock.prices",from = "2016-10-24",to = "2019-10-25")`

ISIN:

`test2 <- tq_get("US01609W1027",get = "stock.prices",from = "2016-10-24",to = "2019-10-25")`

Error Message:

`x = 'BP41ZD1', get = 'stock.prices': Error: BP41ZD1 download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 404.
x = 'US01609W1027', get = 'stock.prices': Error: US01609W1027 download failed after two attempts. Error message:
HTTP error 404.`

I would expect this to work just as if "AAPL" or "MSFT" was in the ticker value, ideally.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Update: I kind of figured it out... but it is not working great. I will likely have to break out each exchange and format as I did for Hong Kong in order for it to search on Yahoo finance. Essentially I needed to add '.XX' after the tickers for the respective exchanges (i.e. .HK for Hong Kong or .L for London). Here is what I ended up doing, if anyone else experiences this issue:

```
ixus_adr <- ixus %>%
  filter(exchange %in% c("NASDAQ","New York Stock Exchange Inc."))

ixus_hk <- ixus %>%
  filter(exchange == "Hong Kong Exchanges And Clearing Ltd") 
ixus_hk$ticker <- str_replace_all(ixus_hk$ticker, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")
ixus_hk$ticker <- as.numeric(ixus_hk$ticker) 
ixus_hk$ticker <- str_pad(ixus_hk$ticker, 4, pad = "0")
ixus_hk <- ixus_hk %>%
  mutate(xch = "HK")
ixus_hk$xticker = str_c(ixus_hk$ticker, ixus_hk$xch, sep = ".")

ixus <- ixus %>%
  filter(class == 'Equity') %>%
  filter(exchange %in% c("Asx - All Markets", "Athens Exchange S.A. Cash Market", "Bolsa De Madrid", "Bolsa Mexicana De Valores", "Borsa Italiana", "Euronext Amsterdam", "Gretai Securities Market", "Indonesia Stock Exchange", "Irish Stock Exchange - All Market", "Istanbul Stock Exchange", "Johannesburg Stock Exchange", "Korea Exchange (Stock Market)", "London Stock Exchange", "Nasdaq Omx Helsinki Ltd.", "National Stock Exchange Of India", "New Zealand Exchange Ltd", "Nyse Euronext - Euronext Brussels", "Nyse Euronext - Euronext Lisbon", "Nyse Euronext - Euronext Paris", "Omx Nordic Exchange Copenhagen A/S", "Oslo Bors Asa", "Qatar Exchange", "Santiago Stock Exchange", "Saudi Stock Exchange", "Shanghai Stock Exchange", "Singapore Exchange", "SIX Swiss Exchange", "Six Swiss Exchange Ag", "Standard-Classica-Forts", "Taiwan Stock Exchange", "Tel Aviv Stock Exchange", "Tokyo Stock Exchange", "Toronto Stock Exchange", "Wiener Boerse Ag", "XBSP", "Xetra"))

ixus <- ixus %>%
  mutate(xch = case_when(
    exchange=="Asx - All Markets" ~ "AX",
    exchange=="Athens Exchange S.A. Cash Market" ~ "AT",
    exchange=="Bolsa De Madrid" ~ "MC",
    exchange=="Bolsa Mexicana De Valores" ~ "MX",
    exchange=="Borsa Italiana" ~ "MI",
    exchange=="Euronext Amsterdam" ~ "AS",
    exchange=="Gretai Securities Market" ~ "TWO",
    exchange=="Indonesia Stock Exchange" ~ "JK",    
    exchange=="Irish Stock Exchange - All Market" ~ "IR",
    exchange=="Istanbul Stock Exchange" ~ "IS",
    exchange=="Johannesburg Stock Exchange" ~ "JO",
    exchange=="Korea Exchange (Stock Market)" ~ "KS",
    exchange=="London Stock Exchange" ~ "L",
    exchange=="Nasdaq Omx Helsinki Ltd." ~ "HE",
    exchange=="National Stock Exchange Of India" ~ "NS",
    exchange=="New Zealand Exchange Ltd" ~ "NZ",
    exchange=="Nyse Euronext - Euronext Brussels" ~ "BR",    
    exchange=="Nyse Euronext - Euronext Lisbon" ~ "LS",
    exchange=="Nyse Euronext - Euronext Paris" ~ "PA",
    exchange=="Omx Nordic Exchange Copenhagen A/S" ~ "CO",
    exchange=="Oslo Bors Asa" ~ "OL",
    exchange=="Qatar Exchange" ~ "QA",
    exchange=="Santiago Stock Exchange" ~ "SN",
    exchange=="Saudi Stock Exchange" ~ "SR",
    exchange=="Shanghai Stock Exchange" ~ "SS",
    exchange=="Singapore Exchange" ~ "SI",
    exchange=="SIX Swiss Exchange" ~ "SW",
    exchange=="Six Swiss Exchange Ag" ~ "SW",
    exchange=="Standard-Classica-Forts" ~ "ME",
    exchange=="Taiwan Stock Exchange" ~ "TW",
    exchange=="Tel Aviv Stock Exchange" ~ "TA",
    exchange=="Tokyo Stock Exchange" ~ "T",
    exchange=="Toronto Stock Exchange" ~ "TO",
    exchange=="Wiener Boerse Ag" ~ "VI",
    exchange=="XBSP" ~ "SA",
    exchange=="Xetra" ~ "DE"))

ixus$ticker <- str_replace_all(ixus$ticker, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")
ixus$xticker = str_c(ixus$ticker, ixus$xch, sep = ".")

hk_tickers <- as.vector(ixus_hk[,18]) %>%
  na.omit
adr_tickers <- as.vector(ixus_adr[,1]) %>%
  na.omit()
intl_tickers <- as.vector(ixus[,18]) %>%
  na.omit()

ixus_hk %>%
  select(xticker,equity,price,currency,sector,location)
ixus_adr %>%
  select(ticker,equity,price,currency,sector,location)
ixus %>%
  select(xticker,equity,price,currency,sector,location)

hk_data <- tq_get(hk_tickers, 
                   get = "stock.prices",
                   from = t0,
                   to = t1)

adr_data <- tq_get(adr_tickers, 
                   get = "stock.prices",
                   from = t0,
                   to = t1)

intl_data <- tq_get(intl_tickers, 
                   get = "stock.prices",
                   from = t0,
                   to = t1)
```

If anyone thinks this could be done more efficiently or properly please feel free to message me or post on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer](https://help.yahoo.com/kb//finance-for-web/learn-find-symbol-sln2340.html) from yahoo:

Yahoo Finance search isn't designed to search:

- Analysts
- ISIN codes
- CEO names

The fact that the frontpage of yahoo returns the data, does not mean that the search engine in the api will return this. Searching on ISIN codes is mostly relegated to brokers. You could use the API from interactive brokers (possibly via the ibrokers package), but most likely you would need to pay for some of the data streams.